# joystick teleop causes segmentation fault

Tags: joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

joy_node runs fine but teleop_node causes segmentation fault. Also tried it with joystick_teleop_node and it does the same thing. I have the Husky simulator running in Gazebo and Rviz but I wanted to control Husky with an Xbox controller and I can't get these other nodes to work. I have Ubuntu 14.4 and am using ROS Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254688/joystick-teleop-causes-segmentation-fault/) by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2017-02-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-15**:
Which `joystick_teleop_node` are you referring to specifically?

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2017-02-15**:
The one from utexas bwi repository. I tried this one because it had worked for me last year on this same laptop. I tried these two nodes without Gazebo and Rviz loaded but it still faulted.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-15**:\

> The one from utexas bwi repository.

Could I ask you to please always include either a reference or a link to the specific pkg(s) you are using?

As for `SEGFAULT`s, a `gdb` backtrace is almost an obligation. Could you add one? Can't guarantee that will help, but it's a good start.

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2017-02-15**:
I will try following this tutorial and see what happens.
http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2017-02-15**:
So far I don't have experience with gdb backtrace.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-15**:
Does `joystick_teleop_node` `SEGFAULT` when you run it with just `joy` but without any of the other nodes / programs (ie: Gazebo and RViz)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't want to diagnose the problem, but rather work-around it, then I'd recommend using [teleop_twist_joy](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy). It's a standard pkg for joystick teleoperation.

Unless you want to educate yourself, writing yet another teleop node seems unnecessary.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3